# Payload CMS webpack caching error (with website template)

Tags: webpack, webpack-dev-server, webpack-5, payload-cms

I wanted to give Payload CMS (website template) a try and followed the documentation to install it in a new project.
After following each step accordingly, running it via npm run dev lets webpack compile successfully, but following webpack error occures:

```
<w> [webpack.cache.PackFileCacheStrategy] Caching failed for pack: Error: No serializer registered for ConcatSource
<w> while serializing webpack/lib/util/registerExternalSerializer.webpack-sources/ConcatSource -> Array { 2 items } -> ConcatSource
```

With no cache available, each change restarting the server leads to a 20-30 second delay which does not allow productive testing or use at all.

All my packages are up to date (Node v20.11.1, Webpack 8.6.0).
How can I fix this issue?
I won't continue to use this CMS if it doesn't even work out-of-the-box.